# Core-Plot: x-axis labels as yearly quarters

Tags: label, core-plot, axis-labels

I have plots where the x-axis is defined as a number of yearly quarters as follows:

1978.1
1978.2
1978.3
1978.4
1979.1
1979.2
etc

I just want to map the object numbers of an array of quarterly dates (NSMutableArray * yyyyQ) to the points along the x-axis that are 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. In other words, 0 is 1978.1, 1 is 1978.2, 2 is 1978.3, etc. Seems like a simple task, but using custom labels seems like overkill and NSDateFormatter doesn't seem suited to yearly quarters because the length of quarters varies (with or without a leap year).

In my simple-minded approach, the answer would be something like this:

```
x.labelTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
x.labelRotation = M_PI/2;
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:yyyyQ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom number formatter to do that. Look at the source code for `CPTTimeFormatter` to see the basic structure needed. You'll need to write a `-stringForObjectValue:` method that converts your coded numbers into the desired format.